# SQL - how do I order by date from two tables?

Tags: sql, date, sql-order-by

I will try and ask my question clearly...

I have three tables that each contain a date value. Node and Product have a "created on" date and Shared has a "timestamp" date. I need to figure out how to order by a single date... I need to merge both dates together...

it needs to fit in this statement

```
SELECT sc.auto_id AS autoid, sc.uid AS sharedby, n.nid, sc.message AS sharedmessage, 
    (
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM {share_content} AS sc2
  WHERE sc2.nid = sc.nid
) AS countnid 
FROM {node} n LEFT JOIN {content_type_product} p on n.nid = p.nid 
  LEFT JOIN {share_content} sc on sc.auto_id=
(
SELECT MAX(auto_id) FROM share_content sc1
WHERE sc1.nid = n.nid 
LIMIT 1
) 
WHERE (
    n.type = 'blog' 
    OR n.type = 'field_school' 
    OR n.type = 'photo_gallery' 
    OR n.type = 'forum' 
    OR n.type = 'product_review' 
    OR n.type = 'product' and p.field_front_page_value = 'Add to feed'
    OR n.type = 'reference'
    OR n.type = 'video_gallery'
    OR n.type = 'video'   
    OR n.type = 'groups' 
    OR n.type = 'group_post'  
    OR n.type = 'status' 
    OR (n.type = 'event' AND n.uid != '2')
    OR n.type = 'jobs_careers'
    OR n.type = 'post_link'
    OR (n.type = 'news_article' AND n.uid != '2' AND n.uid != '0'))  
AND n.status = '1' 
ORDER BY n.created DESC";
```

(order needs to be a merge between n.created, p.created and sc.date_shared)...

Thank you,

Matt

Comment: btw, that query will perform very poorly - it uses a co-related aggregating subquery. ie it does a heavy query for every combination of tables 1, 2 and 3! With a large number of rows, it may never return. IMHO you should abandon this query and re-think it

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server, or another engine?  The "timestamp" data type in MS SQL has no direct relation to any calendar or clock - it is used in row versioning.

Comment: Please get rid of things like `{table1} 1` - those poor choices of names make your question really hard to follow (and are really annoying, too). Use something meaningful, and use actual meaningful (or at least easy to understand) aliases, please. It makes it much easier to read your question, and therefore will improve your chances of getting a quick answer. :)

Comment: Bohemian - I left out some stuff ... trying to make it easier to look at - maybe didn't help ... but the query works. I runs a community Wall that posts lasted user content.

Comment: Ken White - table1 is not the real name of my table .. just trying to make it easier to look at on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horrifying!!!

```
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN Table2.Id IS NULL AND Table3.Id IS NULL THEN Table1.Created_on
      WHEN Table2.Is IS NULL 
       THEN (CASE WHEN Table1.CreatedOn <= Table3.CreatedOn THEN Table1.CreatedOn 
                  ELSE Table3.CreatedOn END)
      WHEN Table3.Id IS NULL
       THEN (CASE WHEN Table1.CreatedOn <= Table2.timestamp THEN Table1.CreatedOn 
                  ELSE Table2.timestamp END)
      WHEN Table1.CreatedOn <= Table3.CreatedOn AND Table1.CreatedOn <= Table2.timestamp
       THEN Table1.CreatedOn
      WHEN Table3.CreatedOn <= Table1.CreatedOn AND Table3.CreatedOn <= Table2.timestamp
       THEN Table3.CreatedOn
      ELSE Table2.timestamp END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "SELECT AS" to rename the column in the third table for the query